# Low quality answer on bounty, expiring soon

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

So I recently threw a bounty on a question of my own ([Make WP 8.1 HTML app window not dragable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656727/make-wp-8-1-html-app-window-not-dragable)) , which ended up with me finding the answer myself, no problem there as I'm well aware of the fact I cannot give myself it. However, my answer was the highest rated and accepted but the only other answer was a bit of a restate of my answer along with not relevant information.

How should I handle this? Should I award the semi-acceptable question the bounty or just let it expire and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Award or don't award the bounty based on whether you think the answer deserves it. Your bounty paid for the extra attention the question received; if that attention didn't produce an answer that helped you, oh well; don't worry about "wasting" the reputation beyond the cost to yourself.